# How do I connect to a VM using WMI in python?

Tags: python, networking, wmi, virtual-machine, remote-access

I'm trying to make a script in python which fetches several pieces of information (such as CPU name, network adapters) about machines in my network.

The script is currently working on my machine by using `wmi.WMI()` (or `wmi.WMI('localhost')`) to connect.

But now I want to see if it works for other machines as well. For this purpose, I've installed VMWare and set up a Virtual Machine (running Windows XP). I'd like to know how to connect to it.

I've read that you can simply use `wmi.WMI([machine name or IP])` but putting in the IP `ipconfig` gives me does not seem to work. I get the error `The RPC server is unavailable`.

Could anybody help me please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970303/control-hyper-v-vms-with-python

Comment: Yes, I did come across that link in my googling adventure while trying to figure this out. But I don't really see how this related to my issue. All I'm trying to figure out is how to connect to my VM via WMI.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do that I found to be helpful was use a `try...except` statement inside a `while True` loop. That will repeatedly force WMI to connect to the machine and only break once the connection has been established. For example, in the case of the `RPC server is unavailable` error:

```
while True:
   try:
     comm = wmi.WMI([servername] user=[username] password=[password])
   except wmi.x_wmi:
     continue
   else:
     break
```

That should help out a little.